# Access linked custom field values in freemarker

Tags: freemarker, netsuite

I have a custom transaction body field `custbody_siteentity` configured as `List->Employee` and associated with the correct transactions.

I can't seem to access any fields on the linked employee record via a transaction template however:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf>
<head>
</head>
  <body>

<table class="body"><tr>
    <th>${record.entity@label}</th>
    <th>${record.entity.email@label}</th>
    <th>${record.custbody_siteentity@label}</th>
    <th>${record.custbody_siteentity.email@label}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>${record.entity}</td>
    <td>${record.entity.email}</td>
    <td>${record.custbody_siteentity}</td>
    <td>${record.custbody_siteentity.email}</td>
    </tr></table>
</body>
</pdf>
```

First <strike>two</strike> three columns work as expected. However when trying to test a real-world example of the above template, I receive a null pointer exception.

Does anyone know how to(or even if one can) get access to fields in this way?

(I'm interested in the generic solution to custom transaction body fields of List/Record types, and accessing the fields therein, not a specific solution to `list->employee` or what have you.)

[bknights pointed out the custom transaction body field needs to be marked 'Record is Parent' this resolved access to the value in column three]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Make sure you have custbody_siteentity set up as "Record is Parent"

Comment: Almost!  This solves `${record.custbody_siteentity}`  But using a non-contrived example(ie: referencing a real field, not my imaginary example) actually produces an error on saving the template.  The ever helpful: `Exception during template merging.
com.netledger.templates.TemplateServiceException: Exception during template merging.
java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: I have done exactly this: `${record.custbody_agencys_customer.companyname}` in a similar situation. It may be that was before Netsuite "improved" the Advanced XML editor. I don't have access to that account anymore. What happens if you just hardcode the labels? Also, guessing here, make sure those fields are included on the associated custom form.